# How do I permanently set an Environment PATH Variable for any Application Program?

Tags: command-line, bash, java, android, jdk

In the last four days, I installed both JDK and Android Studio to build my flutter app in Ubuntu 20.04.
Afterwards, I did set the Environment Variables `$PATH` to both JDK and flutter using `export PATH="/path/to/dir:$PATH"`.
I also used `/etc/environment` to permanently save the `$PATH`.

Unfortunately, after rebooting my laptop and launching Android Studio I get an error `path not set or not found.`
I am now forced to resetting the `$PATH` after every reboot. Is there a way out of this mess?

Comment: What exactly did you add to `/etc/environment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install an Apllication Software using a package manager, the environment variable path is automatically set together with the executable file. The `$PATH`
simply tells your system where to search for the executable once you type a command.

To verify where the executable is located use `which <command>`. In your case, it is evident that you installed a JDK and flutter manually hence the need to add the `$PATH` in order to have the executable file location known to your system. See [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path) an example; on how to update path after installing flutter manually. The installation guide on how flutter was installed is found [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux).

A quick solution to your problem would be using flutter -the snap version. Otherwise, if you are interested in getting the bugs and solving them choose to go by the links above.

I see you are a newbie in this platform. Please follow the community regulations and you will grow very fast. Hope this clarifies and solves your problem. Good luck and success.